# Stack Exchange adds trailing # to URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, firefox, internet-explorer

When going to a Stack Exchange user profile (`https://stackexchange.com/users/userID/username`), and you click [**All Sites**](https://stackexchange.com/sites), it leads to `https://stackexchange.com/sites#`. I see a trailing `#` in the URL.

So, when I want to go back to the previous page, I need to click the back button twice. Why is that?

The same happens to the list/grid view for all sites: Here is the grid view URL: `https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#` (this also includes the trailing `#`). The List view URL is `https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic`, and this one is.

This happens in Firefox and IE.

Comment: @slhck go to http://stackexchange.com/sites and it will automatically add #newest for back you need to press twice back button.

Comment: yes!!! its happening in firefox

Comment: Turns out you're right, had to install Firefox for that, but it's indeed a bug.

Comment: It should append the latest "sort by" you chose (e.g. http://stackexchange.com/sites#users), or "traffic" if none. In Firefox it fails to retrieve that latest "sort by" data for some reason.

Comment: The same is true for Internet Explorer 10.0.0200.16721

Comment: @Chenmunka but in this case it's "empty" `#` and serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: No # by default in Chrome