# How did you respond to feature requests or bug reports that you accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, meta-tags

I found many unanswered questions here on Meta. That's not strange things but some questions there have a high view count and many upvotes. Good questions should have at least one answer or one response.

What I want to know especially is about questions that are tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) .....
For example, I asked a question to point at bugs on the sites and you replied "Oh ! yes .. this is a bug. We accept." And then, how do you respond to me when it is fixed? Or describe the fix as a answer ?

I think many answers tagged with[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) are refused with "No , it is not bug.. you are wrong blah blah...." or "I don't agree your feature request because..." .

My question's main point is, why don't you create [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports sections? Instead of doing that, you created question tags and some questions that you reply to have no answers!

Comment: Not all bug report or feature requests *require* an answer, or are too low priority for the developers to care about.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters , yes i agree. If so, what is benifits of asking questions concern with bug reports or feature requestion ?

Comment: @Cataclysm if reported properly or asked correctly, bug report or feature request does have good chance to get the team attention. That's the benefit.

Comment: @Cataclysm: Because the Stack Exchange development team cares about what people think about the sites, and appreciate bug reports. A quality, well worded and researched bug report or feature request always will get due consideration.

Comment: Regarding your previous [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204115/152859) it's totally valid report, I upvoted it. Nothing more we can do.

Comment: @Cataclysm: also, you posted your bug report a mere 6 hours ago. It doesn't look like a big issue to me, so it could be you won't get a response as it isn't that high a priority (the site is still usable to the vast majority of visitors). You would need to be patient, and I wouldn't be too upset if you never did get a response.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard , yes ! thank you. this is acceptable reasons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know is questions these are tagged by feature-request or bug
>   tags ..... Example , I asked question to point site bugs and you
>   accept "Oh ! yes .. this is a bug. We accept." And then , how do you
>   response to me as "fine ! now we fixed .." or describe as a answer ?

If a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has been implemented or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) has been fixed, then a moderator edits the question and adds [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag to the question. This shows that action has been taken on the item mentioned in the question.

For feature requests, site moderators/developers can also add [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tags too.

Note: this is a general practice but not a rule. You may find many questions without any of the above mentioned tags or without any answer because they may be too minor or low priority, so moderators may not add any tag/answer to that question.

Comment: Don't forget the brand new [meta-tag:status-sorry] too! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd need to add tag wiki to [meta-tag:status-sorry] :)

Comment: Also, if you want to see all the feature requests or bugs, just click on the tag names in this answer (or elsewhere) to see all questions tagged with those.